# Delete row from table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rows, delete-row

I tried several method to delete a row from the table with specific Id. Here is the table structure: 
[image: table structure]

I tried to use closest as follow

```
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

and I tried to use this Also

`var index=Id.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;`

To find the row index and then delete but I get uncought error parentNode is not defined and closest is not reacting at all..

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Isn't it easier to simply copy-paste the HTML table markup from your source to here, rather than opening the page in browser then opening dev-tools then taking a screenshot then uploading the image..... Post your markup explaining what you are trying to do, how you are doing it and what is the problem.

Comment: *"I tried to use closest"* Does that mean you're using jQuery? If so, tag it. Also show how you're hooking up the event handler you're doing this in.

Comment: Where are the "specific ids" ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yea see update

Comment: @Jon check the picture  u will see data-Id which is the id of the row in the database

Comment: @Kob_24: Again: If you're using jQuery (as you clearly are), tag it. Again: Show **how** you're hooking up the event handler where that line of code is (since in just about any reasonable event handler, delegated or no, it would indeed remove the row).

Comment: @Kob_24 - the "picture" is very hard to read. Post your actual code in text form.

Comment: Also, from what I can see, your `data-id="1"` attributes are repeated on multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

Since question is not tagged with `jquery` here is an example of deleting table rows using just JavaScript:

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  // react only to button clicks
  if (event.target.className == 'itemToDelete') {
    // get row containing clicked button
    var row = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    // remove row element
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // register click handler for whole table for efficiency
  document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="itemToDelete">Delete row</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="itemToDelete">Delete row</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

use jquery

```
   $(".itemToDelete").click(function(){

        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `id` in table row

You can remove by jquery`$("#"+id).remove();`